# Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: loadrunner

When I run my script I am facing the bellow error in LoadRunner.

> Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error)

Kindly help me out in resolving this error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to be explicitly checking for expected results on each and every request.  Check for actual affirmative content, not just page titles.   Test101, for each step there is an expected result.
2. You need to be branching your code to exit gracefully when the positive expected page does not appear.